# Prove that $F(n+1) = g(n)+1$

Tags: number-theory

> Let $g(n)$ be defined by $g(1) = 0,g(2) = 1, g(n+2) = g(n)+g(n+1)+1$. Prove that if the Fibonacci sequence is defined by $F_n = F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}$ where $F_1 = 1, F_2 = 1$, then $F(n+1) = g(n)+1$ for $n \geq 1$.

I was thinking about proving this using induction, but I was wondering if there was an easier way to make sense of it.

Comment: Induction in this case should be mechanical.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Assuming it is true for some $n$, then $F(n+2) = F(n+1)+F(n) = g(n)+1+F(n)$. What do we do from here?

Comment: $=g(n)+1+g(n-1)+1=(g(n)+g(n-1)+1)+1=g(n+1)+1$.

Comment: Note that we are using *strong induction*. From the induction assumption that the result holds everywhere at or below $n$, we show it holds at $n+1$.

Comment: I would prefer slightly to write it as $F(n+1)+F(n)=g(n)+1+g(n-1)+1=(g(n)+g(n-1)+1)+1=g(n+1)+1$. We need to check also the **two** base cases,  $n=1$ and $n=2$.

Comment: Another way to think of this is that if $h(n)=g(n-1)+1$ for $n\ge2$, then $F_n$ and $H(n)$ are sequences that have the same values for $n=2$ and $n=3$ and satisfy the same recurrence relation, so they must be equal.  (This follows easily, using strong induction.)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\ f(n) := g(n\!-\!1)+ 1\,$ satisfies the same recurrence as $\,F_n\,$ and has the same initial conditions $\,f(2) = 1,\, f(3) = 2\,$ so $\,f(n) = F_n\,$ for all $\,n>1\,$ by the *uniqueness theorem* for recurrences (which has an [extremely short and easy proof by induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1875375/242))

**Remark** $  $ You could, of course, do the inductive proof directly, skipping the language of the uniqueness theorem, but the slight amount of extra effort to understand it from the perspective of uniqueness will prove very useful for solving similar problems.